# Can no longer access debugger in BBEdit virtual environment on MacOS Catalina

Tags: python, macos, debugging, macos-catalina, bbedit

I upgraded to Catalina today, which required updating BBEdit as well. Now I am having trouble using my virtual environment, specifically the debugger in BBEdit.

1. I installed python3 in a virtual environment via Homebrew, set the correct path, and can access the virtualenv correctly via:

```
cd /Users/joecat/venvjc     
source /Users/joecat/venvjc/bin/activate
```

2. I used pip3 to install modules needed
3. I am trying to run this test script:

```
#!/Users/joecat/venvjc/bin/python3 

import pandas 

print('hi')
```

4. The pandas module is only in the virtual environment so it should work. If I "Run in Terminal" through BBEdit, the code executes:
   [image]
5. But when I try to run in debugger via Command+D, the code executes without the "pdb" debugger popping up at all:
   [image]
6. Then, if I adjust the first line to be a "fake" path (assuming this just skips it) it correctly opens up the debugger, and pandas can't be imported because it's no longer using the virtualenv, which is correct:

```
#!/Users/joecat/venvdddddjc/bin/python3

import pandas

print('hi')
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong with respect to changes to Catalina/BBEdit? I switched to using zsh over bash... is that part of the problem? I am a newbie and happy to provide more details if needed. Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Honestly, I’d contact Bare Bones support, or post to the [discussion list](http://groups.google.com/group/bbedit). You’ll probably get a pretty quick response.

Answer (score 1):

There have been a lot of changes over time to how BBEdit interacts with the shell environment. As of 13.0.4, BBEdit will run your login shell to capture its environment, whenever you run a `#!` script. But there are special cases for Python, Ruby, and Perl, since those all have built-in support in BBEdit.

One thing to be aware of: if you've switched to `zsh` from `bash`, a common practice is to copy your bash environment from `.bash_profile` to `.zshrc`. This won't work correctly in BBEdit, because the shell that BBEdit runs is *not* an interactive shell.

For that reason, you should set up the majority (and perhaps all) of your zsh environment by putting the declarations (`PATH`, etc) in *either* `.zprofile` *or* `.zshenv` (but not both). Any interactive stuff can remain in `.zshrc`.

(And if you're still stuck, writing to `support@barebones.com` is always a good idea.)

(p.s. I would not recommend using any BBEdit version older than 13.0.4 on Catalina.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct the issue by **downgrading to BBEdit 12.1.16, the earliest release that works with Catalina, as opposed to the latest version 13.0.2** that I was using.

This may be a bug in BBEdit, or else there's something else that changed this functionality between 12 and 13.

Would love to learn more if anyone has any information on this issue. Google is turning up next to nothing on this problem

Answer (score 0):

In case it is helpful to anyone who comes across this issue, I was able to resolve this by importing and setting trace on the pdb module in lines 2 and 3 (right after the virtual environment path set on line 1):

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

This allows the debugger to run normally in BBEdit 14.1.2, macOS Monterey 12.3.1.

No idea what the underlying issue is. I guess pdb is naturally imported when using the native OS python, but must be manually imported when using a virtual environment.

Hope this helps.